# HTML Agility and Powershell (chech contains xPath)

Tags: html, powershell, xpath, html-agility-pack

I try to check containing "span iteamprop" in div with class = f6 color-text-secondary mt-2 using the following command, but it doesn't work:

```
$paragraphs = $doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='f6 color-text-secondary mt-2' and contains(//span[@itemprop])")[$i].Select()
    if ($paragraphs) {
        $language = $doc.SelectNodes("//span[@class='d-inline-block ml-0 mr-3']//span[@itemprop]")[$i].InnerText
    }else{
        $language = $null
    }
```

[image: ghfghfgh]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are missing the closing `]` of the element node and it should not be `contains` since child element is not an attribute of the parent element. Also it should be a dot `.`   there.
Instead

```
"//div[@class='f6 color-text-secondary mt-2' and contains(//span[@itemprop])"
```

Try

```
"//div[@class='f6 color-text-secondary mt-2' and (.//span[@itemprop])]"
```